# Error "mismatched input" expecting DEDENT

Tags: python

Following this [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/python/temperature-converter.html#02) I got the following error where y = 1; 
I'm using Netbeans 6.5 for Python. thanks

```
      y=1
      ^
```

SyntaxError: line 8:3 mismatched input '' expecting DEDENT (temperatureconverter.py, line 8)

the following is the python code, format it for me thanks.

```
__author__="n"
__date__ ="$Jan 9, 2011 3:03:39 AM$"

def temp():
  print "Welcome to the NetBeans Temperature Converter."  
   y=1
   n=0
   z=input("Press 1 to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, 2 to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit, or 3 to quit:")
    if z!=1 and z!=2 and z!=3:
        e=input("Invalid input, try again?(y or n)")
        if e==1:
            t=''
            temp()
        if e==0:
            t="Thank you for using the NetBeans Temperature Converter."
  print "Celsius Fahrenheit"  # This is the table header.
  for celsius in range(0,101,10):  # Range of temperatures from 0-101 in increments of 10
    fahrenheit = (9.0/5.0) * celsius +32 # The conversion
    print celsius, "       ", fahrenheit  # a table row
temp()
```

Comment: You could format it yourself, using the {} button.

Comment: No, select the code and click the button with the "{}" label. It will indent the whole selected block. You can see the result in the preview window below the edit box.

Comment: You should delete this question, since it has no value for anyone looking back over it =).

Comment: @katrielalex: it has value, assuming my answer is correct :)

Comment: @amnon: your answer is clear and true, but has also been said a million times. And the fact that it was caused by a typo doesn't help the question. Still, I guess every little helps...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the `print` statement you used 2 spaces to indent the line, while in the next one you put 3 spaces.

Whitespace is significant in Python. Specifically, if you have a certain level of indentation in one line you can't just use another one for the next line.

Comment: I don't think this explains the error. You would you get an `IndentationError: unexpected indent` in this case, not a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @Tim: I believe the OP used a different implementation of Python. Maybe Jython?

Answer (score 2):

Use Preferences->Pydev->Editor and uncheck replace tabs with spaces. Tabs can be 4 spaces despite popular opinion that it should be changed to 8 spaces. It removes all detent errors.

Answer (score 1):

For interest's sake here is an extended version of the example. I have incorporated a certain amount of magic which may lead you to a deeper understanding of Python!

And - as I am always glad to continue learning - does anyone else have suggestions on how this ought to be be extended and improved in a correctly Pythonic manner?

```
class MenuItem(object):
    def __init__(self, fn, descr=None, shortcuts=None):
        """
        @param fn:        callable,    callback for the menu item. Menu quits if fn returns False
        @param descr:     str,         one-line description of the function
        @param shortcuts: list of str, alternative identifiers for the menu item
        """
        if hasattr(fn, '__call__'):
            self.fn = fn
        else:
            raise TypeError('fn must be callable')

        if descr is not None:
            self.descr = descr
        elif hasattr(fn, '__doc__'):
            self.descr = fn.__doc__
        else:
            self.descr = '<no description>'

        if shortcuts is None:
            shortcuts = []
        self.shortcuts = set(str(s).lower() for s in shortcuts)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descr

    def hasShortcut(self,s):
        "Option has a matching shortcut string?"
        return str(s).lower() in self.shortcuts

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)

class Menu(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._opts = []

    def add(self, od, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Add menu item

        can be called as either
        .add(MenuItem)
        .add(args, to, pass, to, MenuItem.__init__)
        """

        if isinstance(od, MenuItem):
            self._opts.append(od)
        else:
            self._opts.append(MenuItem(od, *args, **kwargs))

    def __str__(self, fmt="{0:>4}: {1}", jn='\n'):
        res = []
        for n,d in enumerate(self._opts):
            res.append(fmt.format(n+1, d))
        return jn.join(res)

    def match(self, s):
        try:
            num = int(s)
            if 1 <= num <= len(self._opts):
                return self._opts[num-1]
        except ValueError:
            pass

        for opt in self._opts:
            if opt.hasShortcut(s):
                return opt

        return None

    def __call__(self, s=None):
        if s is None:
            s = getStr(self)
        return self.match(s)

def fahr_cels(f):
    """
    @param f: float, temperature in degrees Fahrenheit
    Return temperature in degrees Celsius
    """
    return (f-32.0)/1.8

def cels_fahr(c):
    """
    @param c: float, temperature in degrees Celsius
    Return temperature in degrees Fahrenheit
    """
    return (c*1.8)+32.0

def getFloat(msg=''):
    return float(raw_input(msg))

def getStr(msg=''):
    print(msg)
    return raw_input().strip()

def doFahrCels():
    "Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius"
    f = getFloat('Please enter degrees Fahrenheit: ')
    print('That is {0:0.1f} degrees Celsius'.format(fahr_cels(f)))
    return True

def doCelsFahr():
    "Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit"
    c = getFloat('Please enter degrees Celsius: ')
    print('That is {0:0.1f} degrees Fahrenheit'.format(cels_fahr(c)))
    return True

def doQuit():
    "Quit"
    return False

def makeMenu():
    menu = Menu()
    menu.add(doFahrCels, None, ['f'])
    menu.add(doCelsFahr, None, ['c'])
    menu.add(doQuit,     None, ['q','e','x','quit','exit','bye','done'])
    return menu

def main():
    print("Welcome to the NetBeans Temperature Converter.")
    menu = makeMenu()

    while True:
        opt = menu()

        if opt is None:    # invalid option selected
            print('I am not as think as you confused I am!')
        else:
            if opt() == False:
                break

    print("Thank you for using the NetBeans Temperature Converter.")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea this is what did it for me.  I was playing around in Notepad++ with a .py file that was made in Eclipse, Eclipse was using spaces and I was using tabs.  It looked the same as 4 spaces = 1 tab so I just used spaces instead of tabs and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind the problem went away with the complete code. sorry

```
def temp():
    print "Welcome to the NetBeans Temperature Converter."
    y=1
    n=0
    z=input("Press 1 to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, 2 to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit, or 3 to quit:")
    if z!=1 and z!=2 and z!=3:
        e=input("Invalid input, try again?(y or n)")
        if e==1:
            t=''
            temp()
        if e==0:
            t="Thank you for using the NetBeans Temperature Converter."
    if z==1: # The user wishes to convert a temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius
        x=input("Input temperature in Fahrenheit:")
        t=(x-32)/1.8
        print "The temperature in Celsius is:"
    if z==2: # The user wishes to convert a temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit
        x=input("Input temperature in Celsius:")
        t=(x*1.8)+32
        print "The temperature in Fahrenheit is:"
    if z==3: # The user wishes to quit the application
        t="Thank you for using the NetBeans Temperature Converter."
    print t
    if z==1 or z==2:
        a=input("Do you want to perform another conversion?(y or n)")
        if a==0:
            t="Thank you for using the NetBeans Temperature Converter."
        if a==1:
            t= ''
            temp()
    print t

temp()
```

Comment: Why would you use recursion when a simple loop is better??? In python recursion is (almost) always a bad choice...it is slow and also you can't have infinite recursion! Use a simple while loop instead. Also please, read the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and follow its conventions. In your case all the variable names are horrible, use self-explanatory names please. In most parts of that code you should use "if...elif..else" clauses and to simples "if"s. Last thing: "input" is the source of all evil, expect the one done by globals, so find an alternative way to do that.